# Finite rational sum

Tags: summation

By a direct calculation, it is easy to deduce that the simple finite sum
$$\sum\limits_{j = 1}^n {\frac{{{r^2}}}
{{{j^2}r + j{r^2}}}}  = {H_n} + {H_r} - {H_{n + r}},$$
where $H_n$ denotes the harmonic number defined by 
$${H_n} = \sum\limits_{j= 1}^n {\frac{1}{j}} .$$
For complicated sum 
$$\sum\limits_{j = 1}^n {\frac{{{r^3}}}
{{{j^3}r + {j^2}{r^2} + j{r^3}}}}  = ?$$
$$\sum\limits_{j = 1}^n {\frac{{{r^4}}}
{{{j^4}r + {j^3}{r^2} + {j^2}{r^3} + j{r^4}}}}  = ?$$
They can be expressed in terms of harmonic number?

Comment: the use of powers of $i$ is a bit confuse, because $i$ represent, in general, de imaginary number. About the question: decompose the rational function recursively in partial fractions and see what you can get from it.

Comment: Why don't you cancel the unnecessary extra factor $r$ in the numerator and denominator of the summand?